# Typescript: Infer type from union of types to narrow different type

Tags: typescript

Is there any way in Typescript to narrow union of types to just one type looking at different type?
I want to have infer type on `onChange` property that depends on `value`. If someone passes `string` to `value` - the `onChange` should have type `(val: string) => void` and the same for `number` and `boolean`.

I've created better example in [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAZygXigbwFBSgNwEMAbAVwgC4plg4BLAOwHMoAfKB0gWwCMI42UHggTEIhBgG5cUBAwDCACwlNKUABRFiVGvWaDOvfoOGjxDAJToAfAQR0AJtIC+2bAGM5NKMoYOxAPIKvqroGlo6tIxMVmi2OHieDMhmAHTECEyaJBbYrh5ewFCeXGByEAzA8EjIVNUoYQkEJORUAOTAinSo3VCE1FHMbQA0MnJKKmrZZBCxtr7+EEETzBDT5FAA9ABUUJ3QcsQgsmDAdHJQvcAIfQ4OUABEhKi60Q9Q25u5zkA)

```
type Props = {
  value: string | number | boolean;
  onChange: (val: string | number | boolean) => void;
}

const handleOnChange = (val: string) => {
  console.log(val)
}

const componentProps: Props = {
  value: 'this is a string',
  onChange: (value) => handleOnChange(value /* the only option is to add "as string" */)
}
```

I've tried using generics, infer, extends and different combinations of them, but I cannot find working approach. I haven't found solution online, but it seems like a pretty common use case.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WY562W) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes! I was trying to achieve that in one type, but I think this is the right solution. Thank you!

Comment: You could do it with one *generic* type, but then you need a helper function for inference, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/Nno1om). Which one of those do you want to see as an answer?